# Form With Buttons That Don't Submit Data

Tags: development, custom-component, form

I am trying to make a page that performs various functions in vanilla Javascript.

One of the functions involves submitting form data to Joomla.

However the issue I have is that Following the following article:  https://docs.joomla.org/Basic_form_guide and adding extra buttons has the effect that *all* of the buttons on my page try to submit the form to my component.

Is there any way to add buttons that don't do this?

Comment: did you try stopping propagation using event.stopPropagation() and then performing your required action

Comment: No I had no idea that was an option.  Could you elaborate?  it sounds like the answer I am looking for.